# Voltage output of this circuit

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

LM1117-ADJ in question;

Is the output voltage 1.4V? Have I calculated correctly?

121/1000 + 1 = 1.12

1.12 * 1.25 = **1.4**

[image: Typical Application Circuit]

Comment: You have R1 and R2 backwards in your math... (1+R2/R1) = 9.265 so output voltage max = 11.6V ish

Comment: If you remember that R1 position always has 1.25V across it even with no R2, (I limit mode) then you wont forget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the resistors wrong way around in my math. Answer is as Trevor says. 11.6V.